# Summarize parts of columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two columns in my Pandas dataframe

```
Category   Price
Weekend       30
Weekend       20
Thursday      10
Wednesday      5
Weekend       55
```

I want to summarize the categories and add the values. I want to add all values of `"Weekend"` together and store it in a dictionary for example.
So I have something like:

```
summary = {"Weekend":105, "Thursday": 10, "Wednesday": 5}
```

How can I easily do this?

Comment: One way: `pd.pivot_table(df,'Price',index='Category',aggfunc=np.sum)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`.sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Category=['Weekend', 'Weekend', 
                                     'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Weekend'], 
                           Price=[30, 20, 10, 5, 55]))

>>> df.groupby('Category').sum()
           Price
Category        
Thursday      10
Wednesday      5
Weekend      105

>>> df.groupby('Category').sum().Price.to_dict()
{'Thursday': 10, 'Wednesday': 5, 'Weekend': 105}
```